# Can someone show me a simple working implementation of PagerSlidingTabStrip?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Here is the library: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip
I'm trying to implement it but my app keeps crashing on startup. I've tried to understand the sample app that is posted but don't think I'm doing something right. Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```java
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private Drawable.Callback drawableCallback = new Drawable.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(who);
        }

        @Override
        public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
            handler.postAtTime(what, when);
        }

        @Override
        public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(what);
        }
    };

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final String[] TITLES = {"T1","T2"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
            super(fm);
        }

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            return TITLES[position];
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is activity_main.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.purdue.test.app.MainActivity">

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not instantiating any of the fragments you wish to become tabs in the FragmentPagerAdapter, getItem method. Instead you're returning null and therefore there are no views to fill the viewpager. I can see you've checked out his sample project, maybe take a closer look at the fragments you're trying to add to the viewpager. The above answer looks like a sound implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I am using right now,

```
public class Formulario extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private static final FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
    public String ambitorec;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "tab 1", "tab 2", "tab 3" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario);
        ambitorec = getIntent().getStringExtra("ambito");

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

also you need to add the adapter, in this case :

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // tab 1 fragment activity
            return new Formulario1Fragment();
        case 1:
            // tab2 fragment activity
            return new Formulario2Fragment();
        case 2:
            // tab 3 fragment activity
            return new MultimediaFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

hope it helps, if you need more help ill try to explain

Comment: btw, each tab its a diferent fragment, so you put what you want to be in each tab in each diferent fragment, the tutorial that i followed its this one: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

In `FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem`, you are not instantiating any of the fragments you want to become tabs. Instead of returning a fragment, you're returning null, which means there are no views to fill the viewpager. I see you've looked over his sample project, so look over the fragments you're trying to add to the viewpager again. The above response appears to be a second implementation.